# b64encode with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a python script and basically I am having issues when I use the b64encode function with some parameters:

I am sending the user and password as a parameter but instead of using the part after "b64encode(user:password.." I would like to use the values from the parametes:

Current way(works well):

`userAndPass =b64encode(b"1er24353-353535:880b2b-345346").decode("ascii")`

What I need(it doesn't work):

```
apipassword=sys.argv[2]#'a'
loginst=apiuser+':'+apipassword
userAndPass =b64encode(loginst).decode("ascii")
```

Please let me know any suggestion!

Comment: What does it do, instead of working?

Comment: Only difference between the two examples looks like the working example is using a byte string (b””) while the non-working example isn’t.

Comment: It fails and I get the authentication error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "it doesn't work," I think you mean it
reports this helpful diagnostic:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

You want to follow its advice, encoding to bytes:

```
>>> userAndPass = b64encode(loginst.encode()).decode("ascii")
>>> 
>>> userAndPass
'dXNlcjph'
```

---

Also, you should probably follow the advice of [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
naming it: `user_and_pass`.